# How to show all record for selected row in sqlite onClick RecyclerView and do update and delete

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Hello everyone I am trying to show all the information about specific row in database that already displayed in Recyclerview , I really don't know how to do it , and what data type I should use ?

here is my activity :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.abed.montage.invintorybarcodeapp.Adapters.StorageUnitRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.abed.montage.invintorybarcodeapp.DataClasses.StorageUnitItemClass;
import com.abed.montage.invintorybarcodeapp.Database.MyDatabase;

import java.util.List;

public class StorageUnitActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
    private MyDatabase db;
    SearchView mSearchView;
    RecyclerView rv;
    String nameValue;
    StorageUnitRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    List<StorageUnitItemClass> storageUnitList;
    FloatingActionButton addItemFAB , searchItemFAB;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;
    GetData getDataTask;
    private PopupWindow popWindow;
    EditText codeTxt , nameTxt ,  rowTxt , columnTxt ,userTxt ;
    Spinner brandTxt , statusTxt ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_storage_unit);
        addItemFAB = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_add_item);
        searchItemFAB = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_search_item);
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        getDataTask = new GetData();
        getDataTask.execute();
        addItemFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(StorageUnitActivity.this , AddStorageUnitItemActivity.class));
            }
        });
        searchItemFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(StorageUnitActivity.this , SearchedBarcodeActivity.class));

            }
        });
        rv.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new StorageUnitRecyclerViewAdapter(this, new StorageUnitRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // TODO Handle item click
                        nameValue = storageUnitList.get(position).getName();
                       // onShowPopup(nameValue);
                        Log.e("@@@@@", "" + position);
                    }
                })
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
        return true;
    }


    public class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // pd = ProgressDialog.show(StorageUnitActivity.this, getString(R.string.app_name), "Data Loading ... ");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            db = MyDatabase.getInstance(StorageUnitActivity.this);
            storageUnitList = db.getListStorageUnit();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            // pd.dismiss();
            if (storageUnitList != null) {
                adapter = new StorageUnitRecyclerViewAdapter(storageUnitList);
                rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                rv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
//        getDataTask = new GetData();
//        getDataTask.execute();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu, menu);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        setupSearchView();
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        //mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
        int id = mSearchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        EditText searchEditText = (EditText) mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
//        searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cardview));
//        searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cardview));
        searchEditText.setHint("Search Here");
    }

//    public void onShowPopup( String name){
//
//        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//        // inflate the custom popup layout
//        final View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null,false);
//        StorageUnitItemClass temp = new StorageUnitItemClass();
//      //  db.getDatabaseName(name);
//        codeTxt = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
//        nameTxt = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
//        brandTxt = (Spinner) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.brandSpinner);
//        statusTxt = (Spinner) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.statusSpinner);
//        rowTxt = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.rawEdit);
//        columnTxt = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.columnEdit);
//        userTxt = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.userEdit);
//        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
//        final Point size = new Point();
//        display.getSize(size);
//        int mDeviceHeight = size.y;
//
//
//        popWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, size.x - 50, size.y - 230, true );
//        // set a background drawable with rounders corners
//        popWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pop_up_shape));
//        // make it focusable to show the keyboard to enter in `EditText`
//        popWindow.setFocusable(true);
//        // make it outside touchable to dismiss the popup window
//        popWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
//        // show the popup at bottom of the screen and set some margin at bottom ie,
//    //    popWindow.showAtLocation(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,100);
//
//    }
    public void onShowPopup(View v , int position){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // inflate the custom popup layout

        final View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null,false);
        codeTxt = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
        nameTxt = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
        brandTxt = (Spinner) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.brandSpinner);
        statusTxt = (Spinner) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.statusSpinner);
        rowTxt = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.rawEdit);
        columnTxt = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.columnEdit);
        userTxt = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.userEdit);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int mDeviceHeight = size.y;

        popWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, size.x - 50, size.y - 230, true );
        // set a background drawable with rounders corners
        popWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pop_up_shape));
        // make it focusable to show the keyboard to enter in `EditText`
        popWindow.setFocusable(true);
        // make it outside touchable to dismiss the popup window
        popWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        // show the popup at bottom of the screen and set some margin at bottom ie,
        popWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,100);

    }

}
```

where onShowPopUp() is where i want to show the whole details about the raw selected onClick RecyclerView

and here is MyDatabase class :

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

import com.abed.montage.invintorybarcodeapp.DataClasses.BorrowingClass;
import com.abed.montage.invintorybarcodeapp.DataClasses.StorageUnitItemClass;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by hp15-AY on 04/22/2017.
 */


public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "StorageUnitDB.sqlite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static MyDatabase mInstance = null;

    public static MyDatabase getInstance(Context ctx) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MyDatabase(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public List<StorageUnitItemClass> getListStorageUnit() {
        StorageUnitItemClass storageUnitItem = null;
        List<StorageUnitItemClass> storageUnitItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqlSelect = {"id", "code", "name","brand" , "status", "column", "raw", "user"};
        String sqlTables = "StorageUnitDB";
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            storageUnitItem = new StorageUnitItemClass(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5) ,cursor.getString(6) , cursor.getString(7));
            storageUnitItem.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            storageUnitItemList.add(storageUnitItem);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return storageUnitItemList;
    }

    public List<BorrowingClass> getListBorrowing() {
        BorrowingClass borrowingItem = null;
        List<BorrowingClass> borrowedItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqlSelect = {"ID","name", "brand", "borrowed", "in_office" , "staff_name" ,"email","time_period" };
        String sqlTables = "BorrowingTB";
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            //   borrowingItem = new BorrowingClass(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6) ,cursor.getString(7) );
            borrowingItem = new BorrowingClass();
            borrowingItem.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            borrowingItem.setName( cursor.getString(1));
            borrowingItem.setBrand( cursor.getString(2));
            borrowingItem.setBorrowed( cursor.getString(3));
            borrowingItem.setInOffice( cursor.getString(4));
            borrowingItem.setStaffName( cursor.getString(5));
            borrowingItem.setStaffEmail( cursor.getString(6));
            borrowingItem.setTimePeriod( cursor.getString(7));
            borrowedItemList.add(borrowingItem);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return borrowedItemList;
    }

    public void insertBorrowing( String name , String brand , String borrowed , String inOffice , String staffName , String email , String timePeriod){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
        insertValues.put("name", name);
        insertValues.put("brand", brand);
        insertValues.put("borrowed", borrowed);
        insertValues.put("in_office", inOffice);
        insertValues.put("name", staffName);
        insertValues.put("email", email);
        insertValues.put("time_period", timePeriod);
        db.insert("BorrowingTB", null, insertValues);
    }
    public void insertStorageUnit(String code , String name , String brand , String status , String raw , String coulmn , String user){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
        insertValues.put("code", code);
        insertValues.put("name", name);
        insertValues.put("brand", brand);
        insertValues.put("status", status);
        insertValues.put("column", coulmn);
        insertValues.put("raw", raw);
        insertValues.put("user", user);
        db.insert("StorageUnitDB", null, insertValues);
    }

    public List<StorageUnitItemClass> searchBarCode(String code){
        StorageUnitItemClass storageUnitItem = null;
        List<StorageUnitItemClass> storageUnitItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqlSelect = {"id", "code", "name","brand" , "status", "column", "raw", "user"};
        String sqlTables = "StorageUnitDB";
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        String sqlFilter = "code= '"+code+"'";
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, sqlFilter, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            storageUnitItem = new StorageUnitItemClass(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5) ,cursor.getString(6) , cursor.getString(7));
            storageUnitItem.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            storageUnitItemList.add(storageUnitItem);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return storageUnitItemList;

    }
    public List<StorageUnitItemClass> searchStorageName(String name){
        StorageUnitItemClass storageUnitItem = null;
        List<StorageUnitItemClass> storageUnitItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqlSelect = {"id", "code", "name","brand" , "status", "column", "raw", "user"};
        String sqlTables = "StorageUnitDB";
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        String sqlFilter = "name= '"+name+"'";
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, sqlFilter, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            storageUnitItem = new StorageUnitItemClass(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5) ,cursor.getString(6) , cursor.getString(7));
            storageUnitItem.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            storageUnitItemList.add(storageUnitItem);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return storageUnitItemList;

    }
//    public void updateRecord(int id , String code , String row , String coulmn , String user) {
//        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
//        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
//        contentValues.put("code", code);
//        contentValues.put("row", row);
//        contentValues.put("coulmn", coulmn);
//        contentValues.put("user", user);
//        db.update("CashData", contentValues, id + " = ?", new String[]{contact.getID()});
//        db.close();
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public List<BorrowingClass> getListBorrowing() {
        BorrowingClass borrowingItem = null;
        List<BorrowingClass> borrowedItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqlSelect = {"ID","name", "brand", "borrowed", "in_office" , "staff_name" ,"email","time_period" };
        String sqlTables = "BorrowingTB";
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            //   borrowingItem = new BorrowingClass(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6) ,cursor.getString(7) );
            borrowingItem = new BorrowingClass();
            borrowingItem.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID")));
            borrowingItem.setName( cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            borrowingItem.setBrand( cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("brand")));
            borrowingItem.setBorrowed(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("borrowed")));
            borrowingItem.setInOffice(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("in_office")));
            borrowingItem.setStaffName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("staff_name")));
            borrowingItem.setStaffEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
            borrowingItem.setTimePeriod(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time_period")));
            borrowedItemList.add(borrowingItem);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return borrowedItemList;
    }
```

please used `String` data type everywhere and declare `String` datatype in model classes

Comment: I already retrieve all the data I want to show a specific row when do onClick in RecyclerView ... and I want to retrieve it in editText to  update it or delete it